# xcode simulator is installed but isn't available from terminal

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ios-simulator

I've installed `xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)`, and I've installed command line tools using xcode-select --install. I can check it using `xcode-select -p`.
 but when I call simulator from terminal I get the error *"XCode not installed."* why?

note: I'm using [AppGyver Steroids](http://appgyver.com) and I call simulator while working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't get any help on this, I removed the Xcode and installed it again and it worked properly. this won't be the best way, but at least solved the issue.